# Why does the code promt user for an input but exits without waiting for it?

Tags: c++

I am writing a simple piece of code for a bigger project, now this piece of code asks a user to enter two arrays - X and y.

```
vector<double> X;

double element;

while (cin >> element) 
    {
        X.push_back(element);
    }

cout << "Enter array y: " << endl;

vector<double> y;

while (cin >> element)
    {
        y.push_back(element);
    }
```

The user successfully enters the first array, but right after being promted to enter the second array, the program exits.
I believe it has something to do with the fact, that the first array is read until the user enters an element that is outside the 'double' format. For instance, the array X is pushed into the X variable until the user enters ';'. After that the second time the while loop starts, cin already sees the ';' and that is why the second array never gets to be entered. Is it correct? How do I go about it?
These lines are something like within my first 500 lines of c++ code in my life, so don't go easy on me!

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: did you read any reference about istream or just try to guess how it works? If you want to guess why you ask us to spoil the fun?

Comment: @ÖöTiib, its my special kind of fun :)

Comment: @underscore_d, yes thanks a lot!

Comment: @ÖöTiib and frankly speaking, i have come to guessing that cin does not see further than the failed <double> entered in the first array, but thats about it for a beginner. i did not think it could be reset ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first loop will go on for as long as extracting a `double` succeeds. When it eventually fails, the stream (`std::cin`) is set in a failed state and any further extraction will also fail, so your second loop will fail immediately.

One possible way to fix that is do reset the state and ignore the rest of the line after your loops:

```
// reset the failed state
std::cin.clear();

// ignore the rest of the line
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```